# Conflict 409 Error Triggering webjob running on multiple webapp instances

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I've hosted a NodeJS webjob on a webapp that has 5 running instances.
I'm triggering the webjob using the Kudu API

```
https://xyz.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/webjobname/run
```

The first request is accepted and webjob starts running but any subsequent request is giving error because the job is in running state.

```
HTTP 409 Cannot start a new run since job is already running.
```

I expect that I should be able trigger using the REST endpoint 5 times and another instance of webapp hosting the "free" job should pick it up. Is that not possible? Can you only trigger a single webjob despite of number of webapp instances you're running?

Increased scaling of App service plan to 5 instances and tried triggering the 'triggered webjob' with KUDU API
Expectations : Should be able to submit 5 requests since the 'free instance' will handle the request
Actual : First request is submitted with HTTP 202, any other request fails with 409 until the first  webjob finishes running.

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to run the same job which is already in running state.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the job is running. My intention is to submit another request so that another instance of webapp(since I have multiple) can handle the new request.

Comment: May be the jobs are trying to access the same resource which is causing the error.

Comment: To test this, I kept only a Logging statement and reading Job Args in the function. It still throws 409. It shouldn't be a code issue related to resource sharing. It could be an Azure issue

Comment: AFAIK,this is the expected behaviour when running the jobs in KUDU api.

Comment: Is there any other way to trigger webjob in parallel? My usecase must have jobs running in parallel when triggered otherwise webjob is not a good fit

Comment: Instead of running the web job directly, try to use Azure Storage Queue.

Comment: Another alternative is to use Logic Apps.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep this question open for any other way to trigger in parallel/anyone can confirm that it's not possible. Thanks for the info, I'll look into those meanwhile!

Comment: Is your Job Continuous or triggered.If it is triggered try to run a continuous job and check whether it is allowing to run multiple instances.

Comment: Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#multiple-instances) once.

Comment: It's a triggered job since I want to pass some params in the KUDU Api call, do some processing and stop. However if this doesn't work, I'll check continuous job, which can listen to a queue and process. I've gone through the documentation, it doesn't say any where that you can't manually trigger more instances.

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601938/run-many-instances-of-same-azure-webjob-concurrently-from-single-web-app) which explains the same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#multiple-instances) to run a WebJob on multiple instances use Continuous Job.

> If your web app runs on multiple instances, a continuous WebJob runs on each instance, listening for triggers and calling functions.

- We can see the same in the App Service as well, only continuous job has the multiple instance option.

***Triggered Job:***
[image]

***Continuous Job:***
Continuous Web Jobs can be scaled to run multiple instances.

[image]

***Using KUDU API:***

[image]

> Increased scaling of App service plan to 5 instances and tried triggering the 'triggered webjob' with KUDU API Expectations :

As triggered jobs run only in single instance scaling up of the App Service plan does not make any changes.

Also refer the SOThreads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601938/run-many-instances-of-same-azure-webjob-concurrently-from-single-web-app)  and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710755/will-an-azure-web-job-run-on-multiple-instances) which explains running multiple instances of Web Jobs at once.